# Use transform.LookAt freezing Y rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[EDIT]
Solved with:

`Vector3 relativePos = hit.point - pivot.transform.position;
        Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos).eulerAngles;
        pivot.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, rotation.y);`

Hello i recently came across  a problem.
I'm trying to make this object to look at my raycast point, without having to rotate it.
As yu can see from the picture the script is not working properly.

[image: the standard "gun"]
[image: the "gun" after the transformation]

The code I'm using:

```
Ray ray = theCamera.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5F, 0.5F, 0));
    RaycastHit hit;
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
    pivot.transform.LookAt(hit.point);
    pivot.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, pivot.transform.rotation.y, 0, 0)
```

The question:
Is possible to make the "blue arrow" to look at the "hit.point" remaining in the same rotation plane?
Sorry for the bad explanation but i'll post aslo an image of the result I'd like to achieve(the red cube is the raycast point).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just want to rotate on Y, not X & Z? In any event you should never modify or create a Quaternion out of parts, use the built in methods:

```
Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos).Euler
public Quaternion rotationAdjusted = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
transform.rotation = rotationAdjusted
```

See [Quternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) and [Quaternion.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html)

Comment: `Vector3 relativePos = hit.point - pivot.transform.position;
        Vector3 rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos).eulerAngles;
        Quaternion rotationAdjusted = Quaternion.Euler(0, pivot.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        pivot.transform.rotation = rotationAdjusted;` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
// Keep the Y component the same as your transform
pivot.transform.LookAt(new Vector3(hit.point.x, this.transform.position.y, hit.point.z));
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The problem remains the same

Comment: Did you remove the quaternion rotation adjustment? You currently have two rotations going on.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is just to rotate the object around the Y axis, in the direction of the hit.point, without affectin X and Z axis...

... Then in that case, I believe freezing X and Z rotation will do the trick.

You can do that in the inspector, or through code:

```
Rigidbody _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
_rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ
```

This is not mistake, as it uses the bitwise OR operator.
Also note that rotation constraints are applied in Local space, not WorldSpace.

---

EDIT: Deleted first unneeded part, as I didn't understand the question from first try :)

Comment: My pivot is a gameobject with just a transform component.

Comment: Then I agree with @Absinthe answer.
I believe relativePos there equals hit.point

Comment: Ok, I almost fixed but still `.Euler` is not recognized

Comment: try changing it to .ToEuler()

Comment: `toEulerAngles` works but the rest of the code doesn't. I will try something else

Answer (score 0):

In my game the enemy will face towards the player but LookRotation() function also changes the x value which I don't want. So I did something like this

```
var relativePos = thePlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos).eulerAngles;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotation.y, 0);
```

hope it helps someone.